# How can I add a requirement to my contract that restricts who can call specific commands?

Tags: corda, smartcontracts

As I’m developing my first corDapp, I thought it might be useful to be able to reference a transaction’s initiator(flow starter) from the contract level. The reason being that although my contract is callable by any party, I don’t necessarily want to allow any party to call each command.

In my state, I have a list of what you might call admins. These admins should be the only ones that are able to issue commands on this list like RemoveAdmin() or AddAdmin().

Instead of being able to reject this command from contract level (which I think should done at this level because this is just another command constraint) based on a reference of who initiated it, I have to instead do it on the responder flow level.

Anyone else think an tx.initiator field  might be useful for permission constraints like I described? If not, why is it better to do it at the responder flow level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the conceptual issue is that, in Corda, transactions can be collaboratively constructed - eg if two parties are exchanging assets and the partial tx gets passed around so they can populate it with their respective inputs. So there isn’t always a proposer/initiator conceptually. So the concept doesn’t exist on Corda’s data model.

That being said, you can take three approaches:

1. Since you don't care about who proposed the transaction, rather that it was done by an admin you can configure the non-proposing admins only to sign a tx if they see it has been signed by another admin. So none of the non-proposers will sign it until the actual proposer has.
2. Make the proposer/initiator of the transaction part of your State object and check that this proposer/initiator is in your Admin list.
3. Throw an exception if the initiator of the flow is not in the admin list:

   `//make sure that the party running this flow is already an admin
       if(ourIdentity !in AdminInputStateRef.state.data.participants){
           throw IllegalArgumentException("The initiator of this flow must be a admin.")
       }`